# How to do a background check on entry into the m2m communication in the query?

Tags: python, django, model

There are models:

```
class MyObject (models.Model):
     name = models.CharField ()


class Day (models.Model):
     day = models.IntegerField ()


class Month (models.Model):
     month = models.IntegerField ()
     myobj = models.ForeignKey (MyObject)
     days = models.ManyToManyField (Day)
```

User with a form on the website introduces a month.
I make a request:

```
MyObject.objects.filter (month__month = <month, which is entered by the user with the form>
                                   <day, which is entered by the user with the form> in month__days????
)
```

How to check the query that the user entered date is (present) in the m2m communication days in the model Month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You [can query M2M Fields just like you would FK relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
day = Day.objects.get(day=1)
Month.objects.filter(days=day)
```

But you need to do [a reverse lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) on the relationship between `MyObject` and `Day`:

> To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.

```
day = Day.objects.get(day=5)
month = Month.objects.get(month=3)

MyObject.objects.filter(month__month=month, month__days=day)
```

Comment: Works! I used the option:  MyObject.objects.filter (month__month = 3,
                             month__days__day__exact = 5). Thanks!